# Investigating whether a function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the following function:

$$y=\frac{x^{2}-3}{x^{2}+7}$$

and I'm trying to determine, whether the function is bounded or not. To find the upper bound, I rewrote the function as $y=\frac{x^{2}-7+10}{x^{2}+7}$, and it's obvious that upper bound is 1.

However, how would I find the lower bound?

Comment: You don't need to find the best lower bound, any more than you need to find the best upper bound. $y=1-\frac{10}{x^2+7}\ge-\frac{10}{7}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph of the function is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so we only need to think about the lower bound when $x\geq 0$. And $y$ is increasing for $x\geq 0$. So the minimum occurs when $x=0$, so the greatest lower bound is $-\dfrac{3}{7}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$y=\frac{x^{2}-3}{x^{2}+7}=1-\frac{10}{x^{2}+7}\ge 1-\frac{10}7$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-3}{x^2+7}$

$=\frac{x^2+7}{x^2+7}-\frac{10}{x^2+7}$

$=1-\frac{10}{x^2+7}≥1-\frac{10}{7}=-\frac{3}{7}$

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$

So,

$1≥y≥-\frac{3}{7}$

So the best upper bound is $1$.

Comment: It is true that the least upper bound is $1$.  However, $f(x) \neq 1$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.